# Checkboxes ticked if user selects certain options

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a problem. I want my javascript file to find if a user has selected "No" they do not want a shield and if "Arc" is selected then it should tick checkbox1. Same applies for "No" and "Ely" ticks checkbox4. Also "No" and "Spec" ticks checkbox7. But if they pick "No" and "Any" they can choose whatever. How do I go about does this.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <select id="likeShield" onchange="showTicks(this)">
 <option value="select1">Select</option>
 <option value="yesShield">Yes</option>
 <option value="noShield">No</option>
 </select>

 <select id="chooseShield">
 <option value="select1">Select</option>
 <option value="arc">Arcane</option>
 <option value="ely">Elysian</option>
 <option value="spec">Spectral</option>
 <option value="anylist">Choose any</option>
 </select>

 <table border = "1">
 <tr>
     <th> tickbox </th>
     <th> shield parts </th>
     <th> description </th>
     <th> cost </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></td>
      <td> arc sigil </td>
      <td> Large magic part </td>
      <td> 5m </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
      <td> arc shield </td>
      <td> A extremely powerful magic shield </td>
      <td> 60m </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></td>
      <td> arc special item </td>
      <td> special element </td>
      <td> 10m </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb4"></td>
      <td> elysian sigil  </td>
      <td> A sigil found by dragons </td>
      <td> 50m </td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb5"></td>
      <td> elysian shield </td>
      <td> A extremely powerful ranging shield </td>
      <td> 40m </td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb6"></td>
      <td> elysian special item </td>
      <td> A special attack attached to shield </td>
      <td> 25m </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb7"></td>
      <td> spectral sigil  </td>
      <td> easily obtainable from goblins </td>
      <td> 4m </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb8"></td>
      <td> spectral shield </td>
      <td> Impressive stats </td>
      <td> 15m </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb9"></td>
      <td> spectral special item </td>
      <td> Does double damage </td>
      <td> 30m </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I think its an IF statement but I do not know how to implement it.

Could anyone help me solve this?

Thanks

Pat.

EDIT:

My javascript if statement:

```
function showTicks(what)
{
if (what.value == ("noShield") && ("arc")) {
  if (what.value == ("noShield") && ("ely")) {
    if (what.value == ("noShield") && ("spec")) {
    document.getElementById("cb1").checked=true;
    document.getElementById("cb4").checked=true;
    document.getElementById("cb7").checked=true;
    }
else
  document.getElementById("cb7").checked=false;
  }
else
document.getElementById("cb4").checked=false;
 }
else
document.getElementById("cb1").checked=false;
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statements have problems -- for instance, `("arc")` is just the string value "arc", which isn't going to have the result you expect (it will always evaluate as true).

Comment: Oh I thought it gets the value of that option which in that case is Arcane. Can you edit it please so it can work.

Comment: You'd have to do something like this: `if (what.value == ("noShield") && document.getElementById("chooseShield").value == "arc") {`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks that does work. But it only works after you chose Arc then you select No. Why is this?

Comment: Because you've set up `showTicks` to run only on the `change` event of `likeShield`, so the function only executes when you change that select. If you want `showTicks` to run on every select change, you need to attach it to the change event of all your select.

Comment: Ok I added the showTicks() to the chooseShield onchange but it is still the same.

Comment: Now you've got a new problem -- `showTicks` takes the element that's changed as an argument, but assumes that that element is the `likeShield` select. So you'll have to deal with that somehow; I recommend just having showTicks not take a parameter, and target the selects using getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#likeShield").change(function() {
   if ($("#likeShield").val() == "yesShield") {
       if ($("#chooseShield").val() == "arc") {
          $("#cb1").prop("checked", true);
       } // etc
   }
})
</script>
```

This attaches a handler to the `change` event of the `likeShield` select, so whenever the user changes the selection in that dropdown it runs the attached function.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. 

Could you show the above in JavaScript form since its much easier to understand thanks.

Comment: This is JavaScript; jQuery is a JS library that makes things like DOM queries and events easier. I'll edit to show what I mean.

Comment: You better start from the beginning, try reading some documentation first about js/Jquery

Comment: Hi eliah the javascript code i came out with, in first post (EDIT) is this right whatsoever however it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery. Checkout [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EjLGy/).

On change-event read selected value, compare and set checkox.

```
$(".conf").change(function() {
    tickBoxes();
})

function tickBoxes() {

    var likeShield = $("#likeShield").val();
    var chooseShield = $("#chooseShield").val();

    if (likeShield == 'noShield' && chooseShield == 'arc') {
        $("#cb1").prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your reply. Would it be too hard to do this using normal JavaScript and also if I used your solution would I use IF statements

Comment: Hi Pad. In general: doing just plain JavaScript you might face Browser specific issues. This is all handled by jQuery. Code is shorter and cleaner. Once started using jQuery you won't switch back. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

But to get this worked you need a form in your html, see the link : http://jsbin.com/oyuxah/2/edit

```
var likeShield = document.getElementById('likeShield');
var chooseShield = document.getElementById('chooseShield');

function checkAll(){

  if(likeShield.value=="noShield" && chooseShield.value=="arc"){
     document.getElementById('cb1').checked =true;
     document.getElementById('cb2').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb3').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb4').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb5').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb6').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb7').checked =false;
  }

  if(likeShield.value=="noShield" && chooseShield.value=="ely"){
     document.getElementById('cb1').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb2').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb3').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb4').checked =true;
     document.getElementById('cb5').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb6').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb7').checked =false;
  }

  if(likeShield.value=="noShield" && chooseShield.value=="spec"){
     document.getElementById('cb1').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb2').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb3').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb4').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb5').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb6').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb7').checked =true;
   }
  if(likeShield.value=="noShield" && chooseShield.value=="anylist"){
     document.getElementById('cb1').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb2').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb3').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb4').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb5').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb6').checked =false;
     document.getElementById('cb7').checked =false;
   }

 }
```

Comment: Hi Jai thanks for your reply. Could you try and do this without JQuery so I can understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Like my version in the first post.

Comment: @Pat check i have updated the answer as you suggested to make it with javascript only no jquery.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a Javascript script (inline or not) that will be able to modify/check the DOM.

Your answer is here: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: You provided zero useful information here. That's not an answer.

Comment: The only information we can provide is a documentation about core concept of Javascript or Jquery

Comment: I do have a external file: <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascript.js"></script>

Comment: I think a basic example is in order.

Comment: So why don't you answer this question?

Comment: I have done an IF statement in the first post. Could you see why it is not working? Thanks